# Search/Find file using file name in IntelliJ Idea (In Mac)?

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

keyboard shortcut to find/search and open file using file name in IntelliJ idea in Mac?

I tried following, but they are not working with latest version...

<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

**[or]**

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

Answer (score 50):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice and then type name. I'm not sure if you are asking about this but that's my guess. Or maybe you are asking about <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> ;> There you have list:
https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_mac.pdf

Comment: Yes, double shift was the one I was looking for. Thanks mate.

Comment: command+shift+O did it for me - thanks!